# there is no row at position 0 error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

i am fetching data from sql table through edit link in gridview on clicking on edit it shows error as there is no row at position 0 , i have inserted a data in sql table having one primary key, following is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class admin_updateSubCategory : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con;
    string conn;
    SqlCommand cmd;
    DataSet ds;
    private int sfmId = 0;

    int a = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["name"] == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("../login.aspx");
        }

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {

            BindControlvalues();

        } 



    }
    private void BindControlvalues()
    {
        conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conStringLingayat"].ConnectionString;
        con = new SqlConnection(conn);
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from sfm where sfmId=" +sfmId, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        con.Close();
        ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            txtsfmId.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            txthfmId.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
            txtsfmName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
            txtsfmMiddleName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
            txtsfmSurname.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
            txtsfmRelationHFM.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
            txtsfmEmail.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
            txtsfmAge.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
            datepicker.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
            ddlsfmMaritalStatus.SelectedItem.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString();
            txtsfmEducation.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
            txtsfmMobContact.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
            txtsfmWork.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
            txtsfmWorkAddr.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();
            ddlsfmBloodGroup.SelectedItem.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][14].ToString();
            ddlsfmBloodDonate.SelectedItem.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][15].ToString();
            ddlsfmVLCOMember.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][16].ToString();
            txtsfmSocialWorkName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][17].ToString();
            txtsfmSocialWorkStatus.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][18].ToString();
            txtsfmPoliticalPartyName.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][19].ToString();
            txtsfmPoliticalStatus.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][20].ToString();
        }
        else {
            this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "ex", "alert('Error occured');window.location='deleteSubCategory.aspx';", true);
        }

    }
```

please help to solve this error..

Comment: Have you debugged at line `ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][1]` what does it say.

Comment: yes it shows same error !

Comment: does the query return a result?  Especially with the sfmId that is being used?

Comment: @gmalenko hi,  inserting and showing data in gridview is running well,only when i click on edit to fetch gridview data and display it  to another page it shows that error!

Comment: @rupesh I understand.  But if you run the sql query "select * from sfm where sfmId=" +sfmId" actually return a result?  If you fill in a proper sfmId?

Answer (score 0):

The error ideally indicates that no results were returned from your sql query.

You need to change your query like -

```
string query = "select * from sfm where sfmId='" + sfmId + "'";
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
```

Although I would tell you to parameterize your sql query to avoid SQL injection attack.

I would suggest you to add a null and count check.

```
if (ds.Tables[0]!=null &&  ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
      //retrieve row cell values
      DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0];
}
else
{
      //Nothing returned
}
```

Comment: it shows error on length as there is no definition for length

Comment: @rupesh check now.

Comment: ok i tried again with your code, still happens same! or return no data , form shows blank controls

Comment: Check sql query.it does not return any result for given value

Comment: what should be the query then?